# Show new field after button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I want to make a field that only shows up after a button click.
Heres my code so far:

```
            <div class="control-group" style="display:none" id="passwordfield">
                <label class="control-label">Password:</label>

                <div class="controls"><input id="pw" type="password"></div>
            </div>
```

The "display:none" makes it invisible, after that I have my button and a javascript which should change the display to "block", thus making it visible again.

```
            <div style="padding-left: 160px;padding-bottom:20px">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showPWField()">Log-In</button>
                <script>
                    function showPWField() {
                        document.getElementByID("passwordfield").style.display = "block";
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
```

But it just doesnt work. The function gets called I tested that with an alert, but I just can't change the style :/

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: `getElementByID()` != `getElementById()` as _Javascript is case sensitive_.

Comment: If you had looked at the JavaScript console, you would have seen `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function` - this can be helpful to diagnose problems that you think are correct. Check out https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Damn that was a stupid mistake. I literally copied it off a javascript wiki. Damn. Thanks everyone for showing it me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is that `getElementByID` does not exist, you should use `getElementById`:

```
function showPWField() {
    document.getElementById("passwordfield").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="control-group" style="display:none" id="passwordfield">
                <label class="control-label">Password:</label>

                <div class="controls"><input id="pw" type="password"></div>
            </div>

      <div style="padding-left: 160px;padding-bottom:20px">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showPWField()">Log-In</button>
            <script>
                function showPWField() {
                    document.getElementById("passwordfield").style.display = "block";
                }
            </script>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a case sensitive,the method you used is getElementByID() won't work in javascript, better to use getElementById()

function showPWField() {
    document.getElementById("passwordfield").style.display = "block";
}`enter code here`